# QStandardItemModel not always updating a QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing a GUI C++/Qt FTP (Windows/Ubuntu) client based on my C++ FTP client class (libcURL wrapper).

I use a QTreeView to display remote FTP folders/files. When the user clicks on a subdirectory, I take back the index of the selected directory and I add items to it:

```
QStandardItemModel* m_DistantModel; // from GUI thread class
QModelIndex*  m_SelectedIndex; // from FTPThread class
const MzFTP* m_pOwner; // from FTPThread class
//....
QStandardItem* item;
QStandardItem* itemParent;
//....
item = new QStandardItem(QIcon(QStringLiteral(":/icons/file.png")),QString::fromStdString(itFTPItem));
itemParent = m_pOwner->m_DistantModel->itemFromIndex(*m_SelectedIndex);
itemParent->appendRow(item);
```

The added rows to the selected element (itemParent) don't always show up in the QTreeView, in Windows, they always show up in the release build but not in the debug one (I must debug step by step so they can be shown) on Ubuntu it's the inverse : in Debug mode they always show up but not in the release.

How can I refresh the QStandardItemModel just like the QDirModel with the refresh method() or another technique?

UPDATE: If "item" is dynamically allocated in the worker thread heap (that I delete after it's finished), does its heap disappears too ?

Comment: I don't know if I correctly understood your question, but, have I think you should look at the model's signals.

void rowsAboutToBeInserted(const QModelIndex & parent, int start, int end)


void rowsInserted(const QModelIndex & parent, int start, int end)


http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#signals

Comment: Did you correctly connect the signales between the `QStandardItemModel` and the `QTreeView` (or whatever you are using)?

Comment: I don't have to handle signals as I already tied the View with the model in the constructor of the GUI class : ui->uiTreeDistantFolder->setModel(m_DistantModel);

Comment: You don't nearly show enough code to diagnose this.

Comment: @KubaOber If "item" is dynamically allocated in the worker thread heap (that I delete after it's finished), does this heap disappears too ? maybe that's the reason of this strange behavior.

Comment: Again, you're not showing any code, nor providing description sufficient to tell you what you're doing wrong. I have no idea what you mean by a "heap" "disappearing". Such terms are not necessary to describe the meaning of a C++ program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by sending signals from the QThread to the GUI Thread to execute a slot that will add items to a selected index.